# DB collation and chartset setting in Mysql (in Laravel)

Tags: mysql, database, laravel-5, character-encoding, collation

I am using external DB(charset:latin1_swedish_ci, collation=latin1, MyISAM) with internal DB(utf8mb4_unicode_ci, utf8mb4, InnoDB).

> - customer_name : collation = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
> - customer_email  : collation = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

So everytime I get the below exception warning when getting data from external DB.

How should I modify DB setting in my situation? Thanks.

---

**(3/3) QueryException**

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF8peri ...' for column 'customer_name' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `customers` (`id`, `customer_name`, `customer_email`) values (10008, Olsen Naen Klist�pe AS, naen@klist.no))

---

**external DB**
[image]

**Internal DB**
[image]

---

**Test System : Win10(64bit), Mysql(v5.7.19, InnoDB), PHP(v7.1), Laravel(v5.4)**

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648829/mysql-setting-for-correct-character-and-collation-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

If that was supposed to be `ø`, then you need do *one* of two things:

- Switch the *encoding* of text in the client from latin1 to UTF-8.
- Tell MySQL that the client is conversing in latin1.

Other charset debugging:  [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)